# How to write an uncurry function in Haskell to create a record from a tuple?

Tags: haskell

I have following record definition:

```hs
data EmailConfig = EmailConfig {
  id :: UUID,
  fromName :: ByteString,
  fromEmail :: ByteString,
  apiKey :: ByteString
}
```

I get a tuple from DB operation of type:

```hs
type EmailConfig = (UUID, ByteString, ByteString, ByteString)
```

So, now I need to build a function such that:

```hs
type MapperFn = (UUID, B.ByteString, B.ByteString, B.ByteString) -> EmailConfig
```

I can literally map these things one by one and create a record but I understand that Haskell has `uncurry` function which can be used and this can be made more generic. But how can I use `uncurry` for a 4-element tuple.

Comment: Tuples of size >3 are seldom a good idea. Why don't you just work with the records as they are the whole way? That said: the function you're asking for is usually called [`uncurry4`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=uncurry4), but it's not in the standard libraries; rather, people tend to define it ad-hoc when needed for some unusual reason.

Comment: What DB library? The ones I'm familiar with have enough ad-hoc polymorphism available to return an `EmailConfig` directly rather than a tuple.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's exactly what I need `uncurry4`. I thought there would be some way I can use [uncurry](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) from the Prelude to achieve this.

Comment: @DanielWagner I am using [postgresql-typed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-typed). I thought the same but I could not find anything to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If this function existed, you would find it by [searching on Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c%20-%3E%20d%20-%3E%20e)%20-%3E%20((a%2C%20b%2C%20c%2C%20d)%20-%3E%20e)). It turns out it does exist, but only in a utility module of some library you won't want to depend on. You can't use `curry` for this, because a 2-tuple and a 4-tuple are entirely unrelated types. Just write it yourself for this type, or see if there's a way to configure your database library to call your constructor instead of calling `(,,,)` to begin with.

Comment: I thought I could use Predule's `uncurry` function in some way to achieve this. But as you said, 4-tuple are entirely unrelated types and thus I may need to write my own `uncurry4` function.